# coreapi must be installed to use 'get_schema_fields()'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, core-api

So I installed django-rest-swagger as shown in [django rest documentation](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger).

And on

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view

schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='Pastebin API')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', schema_view)
]
```

I keep on getting following error,

> File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_filters/rest_framework/backends.py", line 97, in get_schema_fields
>       assert compat.coreapi is not None, 'coreapi must be installed to use `get_schema_fields()`'
>   AssertionError: coreapi must be installed to use `get_schema_fields()`

I have the following packages installed:

- coreapi==2.0.8
- Django==1.9.6
- django-filter==0.15.3
- django-rest-swagger==2.0.7
- djangorestframework==3.5.0

EDIT:

Installed Apps :

- 'rest_framework',
- 'rest_framework_swagger', ...

Comment: show me `INSTALLED_APPS` in  settings.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a bug. It will probably be fixed in rest framework 3.5.1

See this issue: 
https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/4601#event-831195901

Comment: Indeed.. the latest commit on master fixes this issue already

Answer (score 8):

try installing coreapi, this worked for me

`pip install coreapi pyyaml`